# Let $f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}\cos(xt)dt$, then $xf(x) = 2f'(x)$

Tags: analysis

My attempt:

From a previous exercise we know that $f'(x)$ exists and is continious. So $$-2f'(x) = 2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}te^{-t^2}\sin(xt)dt.$$ And consequently $$f(x) + 2f'(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}(2t\sin(xt) + x\cos(xt))dt.$$ Now I want this to be equal to $0$, but it isn't. So I probably did something wrong with respect to convergence somewhere, but I don't see where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just integrate by part:

$$
\begin{align*}
x f(x) & = {} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-t^2} x \cos(xt) \; dt \\[2mm]
 & = \Big[ e^{-t^2} \sin(xt) \Big]_{t=-\infty}^{t=+\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Big[ \frac{d}{dt}e^{-t^2} \Big] \sin(xt) \; dt \\[2mm]
 & = 2 \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-t^2} t \sin(xt) \; dt \\[2mm]
 & = 2f'(x).
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Why does $[e^{-t^2}\sin(xt)]^{t = \infty}_{t = -\infty}$? By definition $[e^{-t^2}\sin(xt)]^{t = \infty}_{t = -\infty} = \lim_{a \to \infty}\lim_{b \to \infty}(e^{-a^2}\sin(xa) - e^{-b^2}\sin(xb))$ and while $e^{-i^2}$ converges to 1 as $i \to \infty}$, $\sin(xi)$ does not converge, so why is the limit not undefined?

Comment: At $t \to \infty$, $e^{-t^2}$ goes to 0 and $\sin(xt)$ remains bounded. The product of these two goes to 0. [If you're not convinced, try to prove it] Same as $t \to -\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that by integrating by parts
\begin{align*}2f'(x) &= -2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}te^{-t^2}\sin(xt)dt=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(xt)d(e^{-t^2})
\\
&=\left[e^{-t^2}\sin(xt)\right]_{t=-\infty}^{+\infty}-x\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}\cos(xt)dx=xf(x).
\end{align*}